# C# SharePoint Error: The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am getting ***SharePoint Error: The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes error while uploading large file.***

Can you please help me
Below is my code:

```
        Folder currentRunFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + newFolderName);
        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation { Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@p), Url = Path.GetFileName(@p), Overwrite = true };
        currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
        currentRunFolder.Update();

        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is SP online or onPrem?
if onPrem You may first try to extend a bit the settings

- extend the max file upload on CA for this web application,
- set on CA for this web application 'web page security Validation' on Never (in this [link](https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/how-to-make-sharepoint-2016-not-fail-long-running-uploads-large-files/) there is a screen how to set it)
- extend timeout on IIS

also for large files you may consider using [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee543346(v=office.15)) method

please check one of my previous answers to a very similar method
[Upload file to sharepoint with httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883628/upload-file-to-sharepoint-with-httpclient/56894596#56894596)
here I give an example for SP 2013 (but would work in SP 2010 and 2016 as well) to upload a file under 2MB using Files.Add and larger files using SaveBinaryDirect